# Hibernate enableFilter not working when loading entity by id

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-filters

I have 3 classes:

- `Event`
- `PublicEvent extends Event`
- `PersonalEvent extends Event`

my hibernate mapping file is somethings like bellow. i wanna add one filter for `PersonalEvent` and before loading this object, i was enabled that's filter. but this is not working. my hibernate version is `4.3.11.Final`.

**Event.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.calendar.Event">
        ...
        <filter name="personalEventAuthorize" condition="person_ID = :personId" />
    </class>
    <joined-subclass name="org.calendar.PersonalEvent" extends="org.calendar.Event">
        <key column="id" property-ref="id" />
        ...
        <many-to-one name="person" column="person_ID" entity-name="org.person.Person" />
     </joined-subclass>
     <joined-subclass name="org.calendar.PublicEvent" extends="org.calendar.Event">
        <key column="id" property-ref="id" />
        ...
     </joined-subclass>
     <filter-def name="personEventAuthorize">
        <filter-param name="personId" type="integer" />
     </filter-def>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**PersonalEventRepository**

```
@Override
public PersonalEvent load(Long id) {
    Filter filter = getSession().enableFilter("personEventAuthorize");
    filter.setParameter("personId", getAuthenticatedPersonId());
    return super.loadById(id);
}
```

hibernate generated SQL Query without my filter. what is my problem? why hibernate can not enabled filter for joined-subclass?
thanks for all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is not a bug, it's the intended behavior](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11485). I updated the Hibernate User Guide to make it more obvious.

The `@Filter` does not apply when you load the entity directly:

```
Account account1 = entityManager.find( Account.class, 1L );
Account account2 = entityManager.find( Account.class, 2L );

assertNotNull( account1 );
assertNotNull( account2 );
```

While it applies if you use an entity query (JPQL, HQL, Criteria API):

```
Account account1 = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select a from Account a where a.id = :id", 
    Account.class)
    .setParameter( "id", 1L )
.getSingleResult();
assertNotNull( account1 );
try {
    Account account2 = entityManager.createQuery(
        "select a from Account a where a.id = :id", 
        Account.class)
    .setParameter( "id", 2L )
    .getSingleResult();
}
catch (NoResultException expected) {
    expected.fillInStackTrace();
}
```

So, as a workaround, use the entity query (JPQL, HQL, Criteria API) to load the entity.

Comment: this problem seems just exists in `joined-subclass`..!