# Why is a Hibernate filter not active when using Spring Data JPA Repositories

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-filters

We try to use Hibernate Filters together with Spring Data Repositories. This works fine for all methods defined in our Interface, but it does not work for the default method `findOne()` defined on `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<User, Long>` directly.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User getById(Long id);
}

@Transactional
public User getUserById(Long userId) {
    Filter filter = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("TENANT_FILTER");
    filter.setParameter("tenantId", 1L);
    // return userRepository.findOne(userId); -> NOK, Filter NOT active
    return userRepository.getById(userId); -> OK, Filter active
}
```

What is the reason the `TENANT_FILTER` is not active for `findOne(..)`?

Comment: Because filters only apply to queries and not to `entityManager.find(id, class)`. This is the same with hibernate and using `session.get(id, class)` then the filters don't apply either. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173894/hibernate-enablefilter-not-working-when-loading-entity-by-id